# System.Progress wrong invocation order

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I'm trying to display download progress using HttpClient. For that I use `System.Progress<T>`. Code looks like this:

```
long totalRead = 0L;
var buffer = new byte[1024];
bool isMoreToRead = true;
ulong total = (ulong)response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

while (isMoreToRead)
{
    int read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (read == 0)
        isMoreToRead = false;
    else
    {
        var data = new byte[read];
        buffer.ToList().CopyTo(0, data, 0, read);
        totalRead += read;
        progress.Report((int) (totalRead*1d / total * 1d * 100) );
    }
}
```

Assume subscribing looks like this:

```
var progress = new Progress<int>();
progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, i) => Console.WriteLine(i);
client.Download(file, progress).Wait();
```

But as a result, progress order is inconsistent, like this:
10, 20, 30, 70, 15, 90, 100, 80.

Is this a default delegate's behaviour, or there's another reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Progress<T>.Report` is asynchronous; by that I mean, `Report` method will not raise the `ProgressChanged` event synchronously before it returns.

`Progress<T>` class captures the SynchronizationContext and posts the invocation of `ProgressChanged` event to that captured context.

When used in single threaded context like Winforms, Wpf, your code will work as expected.

In a console app, there will not be any SynchronizationContext and thus `Progress<T>` posts the invocation to the default SynchronizationContext which delegates to ThreadPool. ThreadPool doesn't guarantee any order, that's the reason you don't see synchronous result.

I believe you're testing this code in Console app or something similar otherwise nothing wrong with your code.

If you need a synchronous version of `IProgress<T>`, you have to roll your own.

Comment: That's right, I'm building a class library and testing it in console. Great answer :)